# CocoaPods `AFNetworking` required by `Podfile`

Tags: ios, afnetworking, cocoapods, afnetworking-2

I've got this issue after pod install. I want to have responseSerializer from the AFNetworking, because IDMPhotoBrowser use it, but when I specify version of AFNetworking in my pod file it cause this error. How can fix it?

```
- `AFNetworking (~> 2.5)` required by `Podfile`
- `AFNetworking (~> 1.3.3)` required by `IOSLinkedInAPI (1.0.0)`
- `AFNetworking` required by `IDMPhotoBrowser (1.5.2)`
- `AFNetworking (~> 1.3.0)` required by `RestKit/Network (0.23.1)`
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? Im having the same using with Reskit and other pods. Installing AFNetworking first got me Restkit 0.10.2, instead of latest version and then a lot of compile errors..

Comment: @gonso, unfortunately this is not a problem that can be solved, it's requirements. As you can see different libraries want to use different versions of AFNetworking. So method I need just in some newest version of AFNetworking. If I set newest one some library like restkit wont work, because they use methods from the oldest AFNetwoking version.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should write this

```
platform :ios,'8.0'

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0.0-beta.0'
```

instead of

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
```

Comment: thanks for answer, so it's old issue, but as I remeber it was connected to different `AFNetworking` versions for different libraries. I've answered on my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add pod for AFNetworking as dependency pod  "AFNetworking" before execute pod install. Download first. Make sure the version is ok I mean 2.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

my pod version is 0.38.2.

the solution is this:add **platform :ios,'7.0'** at the beginning of the Podfile.

the **7.0** also could be **6.0** or **5.0** or **8.0**,that depends on the items in your Podfile.You can cd into the ~/.cocoapods/repos/master/Specs folder,and open the .podspec file you need.In these files,they may declared the version of ios sdk.Replace the **7.0** with the maximum version number.try update or install again.That could be your help.

Answer (score 0):

My pod file is following:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'AFNetworking','~>3.0'
```

And when I install pod, there is a error as follows:

```
jxr-pc:iOS star$ pod install
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
- `AFNetworking (~> 3.0)` required by `Podfile`
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by downgrading cocoapods to version 0.37 or you can add version 0.37 to your pods (`sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.37.0`) and then setup specified cocoapods for your project (`pod _0.37.0_ setup`).
What I did - I installed version 0.39 from my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it heppens, because some of libraries require different `AFNetworking` versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
```

put those lines into the end and it will work;

Comment: I'm not familiar with ios, hence, I only formatted your answer. However, I see in the other answer, they said they have problem with `RestKit` when put version of `AFNetworking` too high

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice solution to it. You can edit dependency of a Pod by simply these steps and then add latest pod in your main pod file. For example I've conflicts in two pods `SignalR-ObjC` Requiring `AFNetworking 2.x` and `ContentfulDeliveryAPI v2.0` requires `AFNetworking 3.x`. What you have to do is:

1- Go to your user home folder and show hidden files if not visible already. Copy the specs json file and and paste it into your project's home directory where podfile is located.

```
~/.cocoapods/repos/master/Specs/<yourpodname>/<versions>/<pod-spec>.json
```

2- Open JSON File and locate the key '`dependencies`', now either change the pod dependency or remove the dependency. In my case I changed:

```
"dependencies": {
    "AFNetworking": [
      "~>2.0"
    ],
    "SocketRocket": [
      "~>0.4"
    ]
  }
```

to

```
"dependencies": {
    "AFNetworking": [
      "~>3.0"
    ],
    "SocketRocket": [
      "~>0.4"
    ]
  }
```

3- Save JSON and edit your `podfile` by giving pod spec path as:

```
    pod 'SignalR-ObjC', :podspec => 'SignalR-ObjC.podspec.json'
```

4- All set. Run `pod install` command from terminal and it will work fine now.

**NOTE: This answer is gonna make you able to load your desired pod but the dependent pod you are changing may have some libraries used by the targeted changed pod. For that you need to edit code in your files**

Comment: thank for answer I will try to check it, the question is oldest one, but when I will need this solution in future to use different libraries versions and will let you know about result.

Comment: actually i've tried it to write in generic form. can work with any pod.

Answer (score 0):

- `AFNetworking (~> 2.5)` required by `Podfile`
- `AFNetworking (~> 1.3.3)` required by `IOSLinkedInAPI (1.0.0)`
- `AFNetworking` required by `IDMPhotoBrowser (1.5.2)`
- `AFNetworking (~> 1.3.0)` required by `RestKit/Network (0.23.1)`

This issues happen because of required **AFNetworking** version **(~> 1.3.0)** is less then of current version **(~> 2.5)**. So please use less verion **AFNetworking (~> 1.3.0)** not **AFNetworking (~> 2.5)**. It will wok for all.